# How to add SUM to WHERE clause

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have an existing query and need to add what I think should be a `SELECT` statement within Sum in the final where clause.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    P.*,  
    ProductDetails = (SELECT 
                          D.*, 
                          ProductColors = (SELECT
                                               C.*,
                                               IsValid = CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(AC.Reference_Descriptor, '') <> '' OR (W.Reference_ID = '' AND W.Reference_Descriptor = '') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
                                           FROM ProductColors C
                                           LEFT JOIN AvailableColors AC ON AC.Reference_ID = C.Reference_ID AND AC.Mat_Type = C.Mat_Type
                                           WHERE C.colorProductID = D.detailproductID
                                           FOR JSON AUTO)
                      FROM ProductDetails D 
                      WHERE D.detailproductID = P.productID
                      FOR JSON AUTO)
FROM 
    Products P
WHERE 
    P.productStatus IN ('Backorder', 'Expired')
    AND P.ProductType = 'BATH'
    AND P.SupplierID = 'S-1205'         
ORDER BY 
    productID DESC
```

This query works as expected, but I need to add additional logic so that it will only return products where, when it adds the Cost values from the `ProductDetails` table that match, the Cost is greater than 0.

I tried adding the following on the 2nd to last line:

```
AND SUM((SELECT D.Cost FROM ProductsDetails D 
         WHERE detailproductID = P.productID)) > 0
```

But it does not work; I got this error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

If anyone has any idea on the simplest way to achieve this - I would appreciate it. SQL is not my strong suit.

Comment: `AND (SELECT SUM(...) ...) > 0`

Comment: I tried `AND (SELECT SUM(SELECT D.Cost FROM ProductsDetails D WHERE detailproductID=P.productID) > 0)` and it still doesn't work. I get errors 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected' under the SELECT and 'The multi-part identified P.productID could not be bound'.

Comment: [HAVING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Tried `HAVING SUM ((SELECT D.Cost FROM ProductsDetails D WHERE detailproductID=P.productID)) > 0` and got error 'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.' Did I write it correctly?

Comment: @jmk I meant : `AND (SELECT SUM(D.Cost) FROM ProductsDetails D WHERE detailproductID = P.productID) > 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    P.*,  
    -- ...
FROM Products P
inner join 
(
    select DetailProductId, SumCost = sum(Cost)
    from ProductDetails 
    group by DetailProductId
    having sum(Cost) > 0
) pc
    on p.ProductId =pc.DetailProductID
WHERE P.productStatus IN ('Backorder', 'Expired')
    AND P.ProductType = 'BATH'
    AND P.SupplierID = 'S-1205'         
ORDER BY 
    productID DESC
```

This is kind of a guess at what you're looking for as I don't know what your table schemas or data looks like. But the idea here is if your original query is working fine, add a join to a derived table which lists all the `DetailProductId` whose `sum(Cost)` is greater than 0.

If you want to provide some sample data and your table schemas, I might be able to come up with a better performing version; one which doesn't have to scan `ProductDetails`.

Comment: Need to keep testing more scenarios, but this seems to be working. Thanks so much!